# Отправить письмо без указания хедера From

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

При использовании php функции mail() не обязательно указывать хедер From, он и так автоматом подставляется, а вот если отправлять через phpmailer, то без указания $email - > From письмо не отправляется. Не указывать хедер From очень удобно, потому что при переносе с локального сервера на удаленный ничего не нужно менять. Как можно в phpmailer отправлять письмо без хедера From, чтобы он сам подставлялся?
Код отправки письма:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$email->From = 'example@mail.ru';
if (!empty($name)) {
    $email->FromName = $name;
} else {
    $email->FromName = 'Client';
}

$email->Subject = 'Новая заявка';
$email->Body = $msg;
$email->IsHTML(true);
$email->AddAddress('example@mail.ru');

if ($_FILES['file_attach']) {
    $email->AddAttachment($_FILES['file_attach']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file_attach']['name']);
}

if (!empty($_POST[$required_field])) {
//     отправка сообщения
    if ($email->Send()) {
        $result = 1;
        echo json_encode($result);
    } else {
        $result = 0;
        echo json_encode($result);
    }

} else {
    $result = 0;
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Answer (score 0):

В целях безопасности емейл-домен во `from` должен совпадать с доменом отправителя. И у многих хостеров есть эта проверка. Иначе письмо не отправиться.

Поэтому правильнее будет не "не указывать", а подставлять домен, с которого отправляется.
Как-то так:

```
$email->From = 'noreply@'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$email->Reply-to= 'mymail@gmailcom`;
```

А вообще для отправки из форм стоит использовать плагины. Хотя бы потому, что они проходят всестороннюю проверку и в случае чего - оперативно исправляются (имею ввиду плагины из оф.репо нормальных производителей)

см доп. https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%d1%83%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-php-mailer/page/2/

Comment: Но вот при отправке через mail() хедер from указывать не обязательно, домен сам в него подставляется при отправке, можно ли такое сделать в phpmailer?

Comment: Не вижу проблемы получить домен ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];) и подставить его в мыло. 2 строчки ж.

Comment: если подставить домен, то ничего не отправляет, необходимо указывать именно мыло. А вот у меня на локальном сервере совсем другое мыло, а при загрузке на удаленный сервер нужно менять мыло. Вроде не значительная работа, но зачем усложнять этим жизнь. Хотелось бы чтобы как в функции mail() хедер from сам подставлялся. А вот phpmailer ни в какую не дает отправить без from

Comment: Ещё раз: чтобы ГАРАНТИРОВАНО отправить письмо из скрипта (не важно даже как/чем) нужно во `From` указать мыло в домене с которого отравляется. А для "своего" мыла есть заголовок `Reply-to`. В него можно писать какое угодно. ЗЫ, Я добавил ответ код.

Comment: наверное у меня на локальном сервере не работает, потому что в файле sendmail.ini установлен smtp_server=smtp.mail.ru и у, auth_username и auth_password указаны мое мыло и пароль и при указании в хедере from какого-то значения, кроме мыла, которое указано в auth_username, письмо не отправляется.

Comment: Используйте плагины (в тч и для SMTP). Это не тот случай, когда стоит изобретать свой велосипед.

Comment: та просто уже как-то по привычке использовал тот smpt, который сейчас стоит. Устанавливал его еще до того, как с wordpress работал. Перейдя на wordpress тоже его использовал и все было ок, но сейчас потребовалось добавить файл в отправку письма и нашел этот phpmailer, с помощью которого это делается довольно не замудрено. А он требует from) На следующих проектах уже поищу какие-то плагины для smtp и почты. А может вы можете какие-то посоветовать? был бы очень признателен:)